# byte array как значимый тип

Tags: c#, .net, struct

Такая структура (псевдокод)

```
public struct SomeSruct{
    public int Var1;
    public int Var2;
    public byte[] Data;
}
```

byte[] - ссылочный тип и хранится в куче, а структура хранит только ссылку на массив. Но если размер Data всегда одинаков (допустим 40 байт), то как его внедрить в структуру, чтобы он хранился как ее часть в байтовом представлении?

Создаю свою структуру

```
public struct MyByteStruct{

    public MyByteStruct(byte[] data){
        Debug.Assert(data.Length==40);
    }
}
```

но как хранить в ней эти 40 байт?

Выделение неуправляемой памяти через Marshal.AllocHGlobal() вряд ли сработает. Компилятор упакует в структуру разве что ссылку на нашу выделенную память (IntPtr), что неплохо, если цель стоит "меньше напрягать gc", но непонятно когда и как освобождать эту память - финализаторов у структур нет.
Также это не "часть структуры в байтовом представлении".

Можно попробовать упаковать "в лоб"

```
public struct MyByteStruct{

     public MyByteStruct(byte[] data){
         Debug.Assert(data.Length==40);
     }

     public byte Byte1;
     public byte Byte2;
     ....
     public byte Byte40;
}
```

Выглядит страшновато. Можно попробовать паковать в более широкие типы, про которые все же знает компилятор (например long)

```
    public struct MyByteStruct{

     public MyByteStruct(byte[] data){
         Debug.Assert(data.Length==40);
     }

     public long Segment1;
     public long Segment2;
}
```

но тогда придется мудрить с преобразованием данных в числовую форму и обратно.

Какие еще есть варианты?

Comment: можно попробовать посмотреть в сторону: [stackalloc](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/stackalloc)

Comment: @Grundy Нельзя. эта память будет привязана к стеку, а SomeSruct не стековая структура.

Comment: fixed же: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/unsafe-code-pointers/fixed-size-buffers

Comment: @АндрейNOP fixed же требует unsafe контекста? Не хотелось бы каждый случай использования этой структуры оборачивать в unsafe

Comment: @vitidev, ограничение платформы, судя по всему: либо так, либо никак.

Comment: @АндрейNOP Подскажите в чем тут дубликат? Каким образом маршалинг массивов в структуре к хранению массивов как части структуры? Несмотря на то, что там в вопросе!! есть пример с fixed - это разные вопросы